# Hibernate/JPA: how to handle behaviour for join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table `A` which has a Foreign Key to table `B`. I am representing these in my java class as follows :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_A")
    private B b;

   //Id, getters,setters etc.
}
```

However the join of A with B is expensive and there exists some use cases where I only need information on A. I am writing Named queries for this and using a second class, for the same table `A` with just the foreign key to B (to prevent joins). Something like :

```
@Entity(name = "AFlat")
@Table(name = "A")
public class AFlat {

    @Column(name = "FK_A")
    private String b;

   //Id, getters,setters etc.
}
```

Is there a way to prevent `A join B` for certain queries ? Will lazy initialization help ? Does there exist a cleaner solution with this as I have the same problem for about 10 other entities ?

Answer (score 0):

The lazy-fetch is **just a hint** to the persitence provider, so you can never be sure, whether the relation is fetched or not.

I do not know much enough about Hibernate, so I am not sure how Hibernate is dealing with this (but EclipseLink is loading the relation eagerly anyway, e.g.)

*Theoretically* there is a possibility to define what to fetch and what not to fetch in different business cases via Entity Graphs (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityGraph.html)
but in the very end it depends on the persitence provider, as mentioned above.

> If you have to be sure go for plain JDBC or create a View on top of
>   your entity, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

The more standard approach would be to have only the entities A and B and declare the relationship as lazy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_A")
    private B b;

   //Id, getters,setters etc.
}
```

Lazy realtionships will be initialized by Hibernate as soon as they're used. If you need the relationship for a specific use case, you can call the getter to trigger the initialization or specify the eager fetching specifically for that query (which often provides the better performance). There are several ways to do it, like using

```
JOIN FETCH
```

instead of

```
JOIN
```

in a query, a [@NamedEntityGraph](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) or an [EntityGraph](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-2-define/).
You can find an overview about different approaches in [this post](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/).

Answer (score 0):

The best aproach for what you want is to:

1. Mark the relation as Lazy, so A will only load B when it is explicit needed.
2. Make two load methods in your service layer, marked as @Transactional. One to load A flat and the second one to load A with dependencies (B in this example):

   ```
   public class MyService{
     @Transactional
     public A loadA(){
       ... //DAO access to load A
     }

     @Transactional
     public A loadAWithDependencies(){
       A a = loadA();
       a.getB().getSomeBeFieldDifferentFromId();//cal a getter from a attribute from B
     }  
   }
   ```

So when you need your A flat object you only need to call service.loadA(); But if you need dependencies you must call service.loadAWithDependencies();

Have in mind that loading dependencies (i.e. call to getB().getSomeBeFieldDifferentFromId()) only works within a transaction. If it is not done this way youll get a LazyInitializationError.